# How do you say, "I would love to talk sometime"?

Tags: english-to-german, meaning-in-context, single-word-request

I would like to say in German,

> I would love to talk sometime.

So far I have this,

> Ich würde gerne mal reden.

Is *reden* the right verb here? How would you say it?

Comment: Depends very much on context. What would you like to express?

Comment: For my feeling "reden" fits pretty well.

Comment: @Philipp I'm writing someone I haven't spoken to in a long time (many years) and would like to let them know that I would be happy to talk.

Comment: @ktm5124 In this case I would use "ich würde gern mal wieder mit Dir/Euch reden"  or "ich würde mich gern mal wieder mit Dir/Euch unterhalten".

Comment: Is one of the answers sufficient? Then please mark one as correct. Do you want further explanation? Then please let us know.

Comment: @RoyPJ I will soon.

Answer (score 7):

Your translation works.
Another possibility would be

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit dir unterhalten

Which is a way to ask for a conversation some time in the future. The “dir“ is used when talking to a friend or close co-worker while it can be exchanged with “Ihnen“ to suit a more formal setting.

Comment: Or "mit dir reden" instead of "unterhalten"

Comment: The original is "**love** to talk" so it should be "**sehr** gerne". And in this context *unterhalten* is better than *reden*

Answer (score 3):

Although the given answer is correct, I would like to distinguish cases more:

> Ich würde gerne mal reden.

This sounds like you would like to talk, no matter with who, when, or what. You could be very shy and desire to step up and talk sometimes.

> Ich würde gerne (mal) mit dir reden.

This answer was given in a comment. It is correct, but has a special connotation. It somehow implies that there is a specific topic or at least a specific reason for your conversation.

> Ich würde mich gerne mal mit dir unterhalten.

For the general case this is the best answer. It implies that you would like to have a chat with the other person on another occasion. Depending on the context this might or might not have different connotations, for example like the answer before, but in general it is just a friendly thing to say.

Comment: That's the reason I asked about more context: To me, "Ich würde mich gern mal mit dir unterhalten" could be read similarly to "We have to talk", eg when your boss comes up to you and says "I'd like to talk to you sometime." Uh oh.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thank you for the example :)

Answer (score 1):

Irgendwann würde ich (sehr) gerne mal mit Dir reden.